# Haxe - How to initialize all members of an array to the same value?

Tags: arrays, initialization, haxe

I need to initialize an array with given size and same value.
For example, create an **array** of **int** that has size **10** and set all values to **0**.

```
Int[] array = new Int[10]{0}
```

In other languages it's very easy, but I'm not sure how to solve this problem on Haxe.
Please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [Array Comprehension](https://haxe.org/manual/lf-array-comprehension.html)

```
var array:Array<Int> = [for (i in 0...10) 0];
```

Comment: Hi, Andrew. Thanks for your answer. It seems well simplified codes. However is there any way without for clause? Regards

Comment: Hi,
I don't know another way, but I'm not often need such behavior. You could wait, maybe new answers gives another way.

Comment: Hi, it seems your  solution is best one just now. For converting haxe codes to all platforms, it's impossible without for clause I think.
And Array Comprehension is good optimized syntax.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I would not use the word 'array' since Array is reserved and it's confusing, often I use 'arr' instead.  No need to type it, that is inferred so it's bit cleaner and lighter:

```
var arr = [for (i in 0...10) 0];
```

A macro approach would put the result in the compiled code which would run faster.

```
var arr = [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ];
```

and is explained here:

https://code.haxe.org/category/macros/build-arrays.html

Comment: For the lowercase version `array`, why would it matter if `Array` was reserved? That naming rule takes away a lot of sensible variable names - couldn't name a `Sprite` instance `sprite` either, for example. Besides, it's not really "reserved" in the classical sense (it's not a keyword or anything, just a built-in type - you could even name a variable `Array` if you wanted).

Comment: `array` is not a reserved word.

Comment: Also if there are milion items, then code size can blow up if you use a macro, using array comprehension is in most cases _good enough_ and not worth the trouble.

Comment: He said is confusing not reserved word. I also prefer arr.

Comment: Mark - With snow flakes in as3 I found that I could pre-initialize all the flakes and then reuse, this allowed the animation to start imediately avoiding significant lag as flakes are created, the code looked crazy but worked smoothly. Macros can blow up your code size but could allows an animation to start imediately, worthwhile trade off, and in Haxe you don't have to type thousands of lines of code by hand for such situations unless quicker than getting macro right!  Pointing out possible tools is important, when and how they are used is down to the developer.